# how to use npm node-uuid package with typescript?

Tags: typescript, npm, uuid

When I try to use node-uuid in typescript, I get

```
Cannot find module uuid
```

when I try to import uuid npm package.

How do I import npm uuid package without errors?

Answer (score 1):

if you don't have typings, do

```
npm install typings --global
```

open cmd shell and cd to directory of your project and do

```
typings install node-uuid --save
```

Comment: **NOTE**:  [since TypeScript@2.0 use](https://github.com/typings/typings#deprecation-notice-regarding-typescript20) `npm install @types/<package>` - i.e `npm install @types/node-uuid`